# commands work in terminal but don’t work if added as a custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, brightness

After things like xbacklight, light and acpilight didn’t work, I tried to add a custom shortcut for brightness control as my function keys don’t work. I found a workaround on YouTube which helped to change the brightness by accessing some file.
Please check this clip https://youtu.be/cbJsH4gr9sU 
When I use these commands in terminal it works perfectly, but when I add the same commands in a custom keyboard shortcut, nothing happens.
I tried other keyboard shortcuts and they work fine. How can I use those commands in keyboard shortcuts?
I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Here are the commands to be used:

1. to increase brightness by 5%

   ```sh
   cd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight && \
     awk '{printf("%d\n",$1+1200)}' brightness | tee brightness
   ```
2. to decrease brightness by 5%

   ```sh
   $ cd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight && \
     awk '{printf("%d\n",$1-1200)}' brightness | tee brightness
   ```

Comment: Please paste the commands you used in the question.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I’ve added both information to the question.